# Using Local Notifications with Battery Optimisation off - will PUSH Notifications be sparred by Battery Optimisation

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, notifications

We have an Android and iOS app build using Expo in React Native. Recently, we added Local Notifications - one which notifies everyday at 9 am and other one when there is an event on a particular day / time. They work fab on iOS but on Android I need to disable Battery Optimization on some phone and then it works.

I was wondering if I should move to PUSH notifications to solve this problem but then I came across this [One Signal Help Guide](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/notifications-show-successful-but-are-not-being-shown#low-power-energy-saving)
and it looks like even PUSH notifications are not spared by Battery Optimization. Is my understanding correct?

Even after using PUSH --> notifications may still be missing right due to Battery Optimization on Android ?

Answer (score 1):

I tried it with my 'android' phone (Honor 8x) and it looks like this would be absolut the case. Battery optimization makes showing push notification more difficult. I am very sure that you as a dev can not do anything about this as far as this is widely called a [***Common Issues for All Platforms***](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/notifications-show-successful-but-are-not-being-shown#common-issues-for-all-platforms). So, like its said [here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/notifications-show-successful-but-are-not-being-shown#low-power-energy-saving):

> "**Battery optimized apps** will have **background functions** (like *push notifications*) **restricted**. Make sure your app is Not Optimized"

Combiened with the following quote...

> "sometimes **didn’t even reach me** until I open the app"

..., which I found [here](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/solve-android-delayed-notifications/) and the **failed attempt to find a method to remove the problem, by myself**, I am feel very confident to say that yet you can do nothing against this on Android. And like already mentioned I couldn't find any options in my Settings, to disable the Battery Optimisation for only one specific app - if I understood your demand correctly.

I hope this answere helps you, even tho it seems to be just a confirmation on your assumption.

If it seems that I forget to mention something, feel free to add or correct me if I am wrong and also if there are any changes in the future, so that isn't the case anymore, let me know.